# how to update metadata of file with tika

Tags: metadata, apache-tika, odt

I want to know if it's possible to update metadata of openoffice file in java with the lib Apache Tika. 
If it's not possible, is there any other lib or api witch can let me do it ?

Comment: Try Apache POI?

Answer (score 0):

please check below URL which help you the perfect way.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tika/tika_metadata_extraction.htm

Comment: thank you for your answer, but in the example he add new information to the metadata list ( metadata.add("Author","Tutorials Point"); ) but he don't set this new list to the file

Comment: Ok,, let me find the other solution fro you... will comment here once i have another idea.

Answer (score 0):

Tika usually extarct content from files,and it won't change files content and metadata.So you can try other tool such as apache poi and junrar to meet your need.